# How outliers influence your results? and what are good and bad leverage points?

Tags: time-series, outliers, leverage

I am confused between outliers and leverage points. And the difference between good and bad leverage points in time series analysis.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Outliers at the end of time series can have a large impact on forecasting and its very hard to control unless you know a priori via domain knowledge what is going on in your time series, see for example in this post the impact of last data point being outlier https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146098/ets-function-how-to-avoid-forecast-not-in-line-with-historical-data/146141#146141

Comment: The terms come from regression. E.g. see here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65912/precise-meaning-of-and-comparison-between-influential-point-high-leverage-point - (a 'good' leverage point is one that would pull the line close to where the bulk of the data would suggest it go (improving precision); a 'bad' leverage point pulls it away from that)